# Execute PHP script automatically whenever database changes

Tags: php, android, database, wcf, push-notification

**THE ESSENCE**

I have a table in my database (SQL Server) and a WCF service that communicates with DB to affect it. I also have a PHP script on my server. Now whenever my table has some data added, modified or deleted I want my PHP script to be executed automatically.

**ITS APPLICATION**

I am working on a mobile application that is almost completed. Now I need to implement a push notifications feature. I.e. whenever there is a change in the database I have to run my server side script that is configured to push a notification to the user.

Comment: I'm still missing the part where you show your own efforts and seeing the reply on one of the answers, I will flag this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637692/execute-php-script-automatically-whenever-database-changes/15637792?noredirect=1#comment22186517_15637744

Comment: I have managed to find a script to push notifications..But now i stand helpless in finding the way by which i can execute the script on DB change ?

Answer (score 1):

Push servicing should be implemented in the layer that adds the data to the database. A database is merely for storing information not for executing code. So in order to create push notifications you would need an interface that receives the updates, sends it to the database and pushes it to the users.

Seeing your question, I certainly don't hope you allow your app to directly add information to the database without some layer that validates incoming information. That's a direct security risk.

A solution of a model would be:

App -> send information -> Website -> analyzes request in PHP/other code languages -> inserts in Database -> push message to clients.

Comment: yes.as i have mentioned I have a wcf service and that is the layer which communicates with the DB..So u say that i have to do something in the WCF to receive the update and then execute the php script ?

Comment: Yes as long as you centrally send the push you will be fine. I believe it would be unwise to poll the database (without reason) to get information and send it to clients.

Also make sure the receiving server pushes and not the sending app; because of security reasons.

Comment: our WCF service is being used by two user interfaces-The desktop and Mobile.. So i am unable to make any changes in the WCF...I m forced to trigger the execution of the php script on DB only...

Comment: so any i m looking for similar examples so that i can learn from those or any links to refer !

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what RDBMS you are using but whatever one it is, you need to read the documentation about "triggers". This should give you all you need to know.

Comment: We use SQLSERVER/////
any links or examples on the above said triggers concept to invoke a PHP script on DB update ???

Comment: You are just as capable as I am of typing SQLSERVER TRIGGERS into Google as I am!

Comment: ha..okay..cool..jus kiddin man..i m really looking out here for help on this yaar

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this is done using cron (or another scheduler) to check a database on a certain interval (every minute for example) to find new work and then process it.

However, that sort of design only gets you so far and the next stage would be to move up to using a message queue (Like gearman, ZeroMQ, etc).

You might be able to make something work with triggers, but generally, a database should not be treated as a queue.

Comment: I m totally new to all these stuff "Cron" "gearman" "ZeroMQ" !!

U told triggers are ruled out.. so wats my option to send notifications to the user when my DB changes !!